# How can I add decimal.Decimal values in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have django views:

```
reviews = singles.review_set.all()
    for rev in reviews:
        print rev.sentiment
        print type(rev.sentiment)
```

It returns `decimal.Decimal` but I need to calculate the sum of the numbers.

When I try `sum(rev.sentiment)`, I get error `'Decimal' object is not iterable`. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to sum several values. Howver, `rev.sentiment` is a single value, so you get the `TypeError` as it doesn't make sense to sum it.

You can either build a sum in the for loop:

```
rev_sum = 0
for rev in reviews:
    rev_sum += rev.sentiment
```

Or use a comprehension.

```
rev_sum = sum(rev.sentiment for rev in reviews)
```

If you have many objects, it might be more efficient to do the sum in the database using [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset).

```
from django.db.models import Sum

aggregate = reviews.aggregate(Sum('sentiment'))
rev_sum = aggregate['sentiment__sum']  # retrieve the value from the dict
```

Comment: Thanks. And one thing, I need to add negative and positive numbers separately. How to do that?

Comment: The for loop example is straight forward, you just have two variables, one for positive and one for negative values. For the comprehension, note that you can do `sum(rev.sentiment for rev in reviews if x > 0)`. Finally for aggregation, note you can do `reviews.filter(sentiment__gt=0).aggregate(...)`.

Comment: Great. Thanks alot. @Alasdair

Comment: Adding abit, can you help me calculate the average too. I tried `Count(reviews)` to count the review to calculate average but didn't work.

Comment: Done with that `naggregate=reviews.filter(sentiment__lt=0).aggregate(Avg('sentiment'))` and `prev_sum = paggregate['sentiment__avg']`